# improper integral of $f(x)\sin(nx)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function. I need to show the following $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_a^b f(x)\sin(nx)dx = 0.$$

Since we can not make any claim if $f(x)\sin(nx)$ is uniformly continuous, we can thus not swap the limit and the integral. How should one go from here? Can you provide any proposal ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: integrate by parts to get a $\dfrac 1n$ in front of the integral.

Comment: IMHO, it's better for a student, like Hans Lundmark has done, to refer to Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: IMHO, the unnecessary hypothesis "continuously differentiable" sets this up for an elementary solution.

Comment: $+1$ Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$